# Flash --> Angular conversion: How can I have a child inject functionality to the parent?

Tags: angularjs

I'm converting a Flash/Flex application into an angular application.

In flash, I have a header, toolbar above, and navigation to the left.  When users click on the navigation, different modules are loaded into the applications main content pane.  Most modules support New, Edit, Archive, and Un-archive actions.  There are icons in the toolbar that execute the actions.

But there are some modules that support additional actions.  In flex, when the child module loads, it loads a new button into the toolbar along with a callback function that will be called when the user clicks on the custom action button.  When the module unloads, it removes the button from the toolbar.

So in angular, what could I use to achieve similar functionality?  Is this a parent/child scope kind of thing or something else altogether?  I'm new to angular and I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having a hard time visualizing the functionality you're trying to replicate.  An Angular Controller is sort of like the "script" part of an MXML Component. You can share data between controllers with a Factory or Service object. A RouteProvider is sort of like a viewStack.  But, I have no idea if any of that helps you.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey! glad to see you've also made the switch over to Angular good to see I haven't lost you in he switch from Flex :).  For the OP you could go about this a couple of ways in Angular.  A service or factory as stated above gives you a singleton so you can share your state that way.  Alternatively you can look at using $emit $on and $broadcast to use events to communicate between components.  Finally with directives you can have a dependency on other directives and access the controller of one from another.

Comment: Reeboog - what i'm looking to do is, I guess, I have a parent controller that controls the toolbar functionality.  when the parent loads a child controller/view, some children need to add a button to the toolbar and handle the click event.

Comment: @shaunhusain I'm almost done writing an "AngularJS for Flex Developers" book; and it should be out in April or May.  It is lovingly called "Life After Flex"